# Ускорение программы и уменьшение памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Можно ли как то сократить выделение памяти этой программы и ускорить её?
программа просто удаляет числа и логорифмирует элементы.пример входа

```
2 #кол списков
2 9 9 9#пер число кол элементов в этом списке -1
2 9 9 3





import math

h = {}
i = 0
acc = 0
for _ in range(int(input())): # пока меньше общего кол списков
    s = input()[2:]
    s = s.split()
    if '1' in s:
        s = s[:s.index('1') + 1] # удаляю единицы такой список 1 1 1 привожу к такому 1
    if len(s) == 1: # если длина его 1
        acc = -9
        del s[-1] # если длина его 2
    elif len(s) == 2:
        acc = math.log(float(s[-1]))
        del s[-1]
        acc += (float(s[-1])) / math.log(2)
        del s[-1]
    else:
        acc = float(s[-1])
        del s[-1]
        acc += math.log(float(s[-1]))
        del s[-1]
        acc *= math.log(float(s[-1]))
        del s[-1]
        while len(s) != 0 and acc < 500: # просто по циклу ещё подставляю элементы списка под логорифмы 
            acc = (2 ** acc) + (math.log(float(s[-1])) / math.log(2))
            del s[-1]


    h[i] = [int(item) for item in s] # перевожу строку в список
    s.clear()
    acc = round(acc, 10) # последнее число округляю
    h[i].append(acc) # добавляю последнее число в список
    h[i].reverse()
   # print(h[i])
    i += 1

# их сортирую
sorted_list = sorted(h.items(), key=lambda x: (len(x[1]), x[1]))
print(' '.join(str(i + 1) for i, _ in sorted_list))
```

Comment: Какая формулировка у задачи?

Comment: Заминусовал за оформление вопроса. Проявляйте уважение к отвечающим

Answer (score 0):

Ускорение, максимум вижу в объединении операций удаления и вынесения log_2 из цикла в константу. Хорошо если Cpython оптимизирует del[-1], потому что в общем случае, удаление имеет сложность O(n). Заодно немного попробовал причесать код.

```
log_2 = math.log(2)
s = list(map(float, s))
if len(s) == 1: # если длина его 1
    acc = -9
    s = []
elif len(s) == 2:
    v1, v2 = s
    acc = v1/log_2 + math.log(v2)
    s =[] 
else:
    *s, v1, v2, v3 = s
    acc = (v3 + math.log(v2)) * math.log(v1)
    for n, it in enumerate(reversed(s)):
        if acc >= 500:
            break
        acc = (2 ** acc) + math.log(it)/log_2
    del s[-1*(n+1):]
```

Comment: Здравствуйте,спасибо за ответ,с вами лично можно как нибудь связаться?

Comment: а как эту строку вставить в код?     s = map(float, s) пытался у меня ошибки выдаёт

Comment: @aleksandr421 Затрудняюсь сказать. Проверил в консоли, `v1, v2 = map(float, ['1', '2'])` работает нормально. `v1 = 1.0`

Comment: я просто хотел,чтобы вы мне за 250р полностью похожий код попробывали оптимизировать.

Comment: вставляю эту строку `s = map(float, s) перед if len(s)=='1':` выдаёт ошибку     TypeError: object of type 'map' has no

Comment: @aleksandr421 Моя вина. map это генератор, который не имеет длины. Исправьте на `list(map(float, s))`

Comment: `del s[-1 * (n + 1):]` вот эта строка правильная ?у меня числа рушатся